# Getting number of MPI threads before calling MPI_Init()

Tags: c++, mpi

I have a program written in C++, which is capable of using MPI routines. Thus my main-function is

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    //Other code

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Now I am using a custom function for `MPI_Init()` with a third variable. I would like to set this variable depending on the amount of threads  which is used in the `mpirun -n x main`-call. Thus I need to know the amount of threads before calling `MPI_Init()`. I can get this number using `MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);`, but for that I already must have called `MPI_Init()`. Therefore, is there a way to get the number of MPI threads before calling `MPI_Init()`?

Comment: There are some **non** portable ways to achieve this, but I advise you against going down that road. You might instead want to revamp your app so you do not need this information too early.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: I can not revamp the custom MPI_Init-function, and would like to use the information for improving the performance. I do not care about portability, as long as it works on Linux.

Comment: Threads? Or processes?

Comment: The value of x, when running `mpirun -n x main`

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.

Generally, you should execute `MPI_Init` as early as possible anyway.